# Append new line when transfer textbox to textarea (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have function that will create multiple id of textbox. My problem now is how can i append this textbox value to textarea with new line.

Currently my code is like this :

```js
var i=$('table tr').length;
    (function(index){
          $('#transfer').on('click', function()
            {
               var tilam_item = $('#tilam_item'+index).val();
               $('#text').append(tilam_item);
            });
        })(i);
```

I've successful in append all the item in the textbox but they are not in proper alignment. I want to add new line when append the value but i cannot figure it how.

Comment: can you add your html also here

Comment: Just do it with a \n appended to text for new line and you will be good

Comment: Thanks ! i figure it out using shiva solution @Feeda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add new line char '\n'.

```js
var i=$('table tr').length;
    (function(index){
          $('#transfer').on('click', function()
            {
               var tilam_item = $('#tilam_item'+index).val() + '\n';
               $('#text').append(tilam_item);
            });
        })(i);
```

Comment: Thanks ! this answered my question ! i dont know its easy like this.